# How can i run a service on Boot

Tags: bada

Hi i want to run a service in Bada which runs on the Boot and it should be able do activities like a sound of some seconds.
 1) How it can be done 
 2 Which APIs can i use.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in bada. If you need to launch an app on a certain time, use launch conditions - use `AppManager::RegisterAppLaunch()`.